# How does Rust know that the lifetime of a vector is dependent on things you push to it?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of references, and push a reference to a value, move the value and then attempt to use the vector:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut my_vec: Vec<&Box<i32>> = vec![];
    let my_val = Box::new(5);
    my_vec.push(&my_val);
    drop(my_val);
    println!("{:?}", my_vec)
}
```

This gives us an error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `my_val` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
4 |     my_vec.push(&my_val);
  |                 ------- borrow of `my_val` occurs here
5 |     drop(my_val);
  |          ^^^^^^ move out of `my_val` occurs here
6 |     println!("{:?}", my_vec)
  |                      ------ borrow later used here
```

If this was allowed to compile, we would get a use after free so it's good that Rust is able to detect that the vector can't outlive things it references.

If we look at this similar piece of code

```rust
fn dont_push<T>(_v: &mut Vec<T>, _a: T) {}

fn main() {
    let mut my_vec: Vec<&Box<i32>> = vec![];
    let my_val = Box::new(5);
    dont_push(&mut my_vec, &my_val);
    drop(my_val);
    println!("{:?}", my_vec)
}
```

We get the same error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `my_val` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:7:10
  |
6 |     dont_push(&mut my_vec, &my_val);
  |                            ------- borrow of `my_val` occurs here
7 |     drop(my_val);
  |          ^^^^^^ move out of `my_val` occurs here
8 |     println!("{:?}", my_vec)
  |                      ------ borrow later used here
```

This seems to suggest that Rust looks at the type signature of `push` and `dont_push` to figure out that it's possible that `my_vec` requires `my_val` to still be alive.

What is the general rule?

From my experimenting here, it looks like it might be something along the lines of "if one argument to a function is a mutable reference, that argument can't outlive the other ones". What happens if there are multiple mutable references?

Comment: Here it's simpler: since both arguments refer to the same type `T`, these `T`'s must have the same lifetime.

Comment: If you replace the two occurrences of `T` in the argument list of `dont_push()` with `&T` instead, the code compiles, since then the compiler is allowed to infer two different lifetimes for the two different reference types. if `T` denotes the full reference type, it must have the same lifetime, as noted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems to suggest that Rust looks at the type signature of `push` and `dont_push` to figure out that it's possible that `my_vec` requires `my_val` to still be alive.
>
> What is the general rule?

The type variable `T` in this particular call to `dont_push` becomes `&'a Box<i32>`. It's a reference, so it has some lifetime `'a`. But there are two incompatible choices for what that lifetime is, deriving from the two parameters:

- A `Vec<T>` must not end up holding `T`s that are invalid, so we conclude that `T`'s lifetime(s) must outlive the `Vec`. Thus, the lifetime must extend until `my_vec` is no longer used. (This is true of almost *any* generic type, not just `Vec` — except for “[contravariance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html)”, which you will rarely encounter.)
- The second parameter uses the same type variable for a borrow of `my_val`. Thus, the lifetime must end before `my_val` is dropped.

We can produce the same error with this simpler program:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_short: Box<i32> = Box::new(123);
    let my_long = &my_short;

    drop(my_short);
    println!("{:?}", my_long);
}
```

In this case, the requirement for the lifetimes to match is played by the assignment that initializes `my_long`. But just like `dont_push` doesn't need to do anything, we don't need the *effect* of the assignment; we just need something requiring the types to match.

There are similar situations where you *won't* get this error. For example, if `my_val` implements `Copy` (e.g. because it is `i32` rather than `Box<i32>`) then `drop(my_val)` drops a copy and the original is still valid. The `Copy` value has to be *inside a non-`Copy` container* so that the `drop` necessarily deallocates the memory:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_short: Vec<i32> = vec![123];
    let my_long = &my_short[0];

    drop(my_short);
    println!("{:?}", my_long);
}
```

Comment: Also, should point out the compiler error goes away if we change the signature for `dont_push` to have explicitly different lifetime annotations for the inputs: `fn dont_push<'x, 'y, T>(_v: &mut Vec<&'x T>, _a: &'y T) {}`

Comment: @effect That doesn't make any difference when the issue is the lifetime _within `T`_ — interacting with a container (`Vec`, `HashSet`, `Box`, …) of references always exhibits this requirement, regardless of the signatures of the individual operations on it.

Comment: The example I show should move the automatic lifetime annotations out of T? With the change I made here, T would resolve to `Box<i32>` instead of `&'a Box<i32>` right?

Comment: @effect Ah, I see. Yes, it would, but then it couldn't actually implement pushing onto the vector, so it's sufficiently unrelated to the problem that I don't think it belongs in this answer.

Comment: I agree. I only mention it because it helps to answer OP's second question about why their `dont_push()` method was also (unnecessarily) tying the lifetime of the "not pushed"  variable to the vector.